# What does SSL do for web applications

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, ssl-certificate

Does SSL provide any type of security other than simply encrypting the content of the HTTP request for web applications?

Comment: Please re-open, I have updated my post to make it more clear as a question.

Comment: What are you asking that Google and Wikipedia can't already answer for you? http://lmgtfy.com/?q=SSL&l=1

Comment: @Daniel, oh snap - I Google for "What does SSL do for web applications" and it points to this very StackOverflow article.

Comment: @JacobT I wouldn't doubt that.  I would recommend that you understand the basic concept and working of SSL before trying to relate it to what it can do for a web application.  I'm fairly certain that once you understand what it is and what it works your question will have of been answered for you.

Comment: To augment Daniel's response: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=What+is+SSL%3F

Comment: I seriously can't believe my question is closed when a simple 1 word yes/no could answer the question.

Comment: @JacobT: Why would you imagine that SSL does anything other than provide encryption? And didn't WikiPedia tell you that much?

Comment: @JacobT: Your question was closed, in part, _because_ a simple one-word yes/no could answer it!

Comment: People, I'm not ask WHAT SSL is ... I'm asking does it provide security other other simply encrypting the HTTP request

Comment: @JacobT We understand your question, it seems apparent that you do not understand what SSL is and that is why people are trying to direct you to understand what it is.  Once you have a basic understanding you will have answered your own question.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security, which is redirected to by searching for "SSL".

Comment: @Quintin, so what you do is close the topic. Why note post those links as answers

Comment: @JacobT I voted to close your original question because it did not contain a question, it contained a link to an article on an external site and provided no context to answer.  Likewise when you re-worded your question to be a question I also voted to re-open.

Comment: @Daniel: How many questions are posted on Stack Overflow that you couldn't find the answer to somewhere on the web if you knew what they were looking for and looked hard enough? Sorry if the poor sucker is asking a question you consider too easy. Surely there was a time when you didn't know the answer either. If it's beneath your dignity to answer, then don't answer. I don't see a need to ridicule the guy.

Comment: I said it was spam because it was a link to some commercial web site, with no question at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSL does 2 things:

- verifies that the site is who they say they are (to prevent man in the middle attacks)
- encrypts the traffic between the client and the server

Comment: SSL provides 1) confidentiality, 2) authentication (usually; there are anonymous cipher suites), and 3) *integrity.* It does not provide non-repudiation, authorization, or availability. I stress the integrity, because it is important to know that *none* of the traffic is alterable in any way by an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @cobbal, only organization-validated certificates validate who you really are. Almost 90% of the certificates in the market are domain-validated and they don't validate anything (that's why they are much cheaper).

Comment: Do you mean "self-signed" certificates.

Comment: No, to give an example:
Geotrust QuickSSL Premium is domain-validated and while buying it, it only validates that the domain belongs to you.

Geotrust TrueBusinessID is organization-validated. It asks you to send several official papers to validate that you're really running an official business. From the eyes of the visitors, they are more respected.